# Hide/Unhide a row based on the hidden/unhidden status of a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to unhide a single row if an ENTIRE range of rows is hidden. I want to hide this row if even a SINGLE row within the range is unhidden. What is the syntax for this? My current code is as follows:

```
Public Sub MySub()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Range("A1:A5")
.EntireRow.Hidden = False

 For Each cell In Range("A1:A5")
     Select Case cell.Value
         Case Is = "-"
         cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
     End Select
 Next cell

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You could just check `If Rows(Cell.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True Then ...`?  Not quite sure what the question is, can you clarify a little?

Comment: So I have values in A1:A5. If any of those values are equal to "-" the VBA code hides the corresponding row. If they are all equal to "-", I want cell row 6 to unhide. If even one of row 1-5 is NOT hidden (meaning there is a value in A1,A2,A3,A4, or A5 that is not equal to "-"), I want row 6 to be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand.  How's this:

```
Sub test()
Dim cel As Range, rng As Range
Dim hideRow&, numDashes&

Set rng = Range("A1:A5")
hideRow = rng.Count + 1

For Each cel In rng
    If cel.Value = "-" Then
        numDashes = numDashes + 1
        Rows(cel.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next cel
If numDashes = rng.Count Then
    ' If all cells in the range are '-'
    Rows(hideRow).EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
    Rows(hideRow).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
End Sub
```

I'm kind of assuming that you want to hide/unhide Row 6, since it's one below your range's last row.  Therefore, I created a variable to hold this.  This way, if you want to change your range to say `A1:A100`, all you have to do is adjust the `rng`, and it'll look to hide/unhide row 101.  Of course, if you just need it to be `6`, then just do `hideRow = 6`.

Edit: For fun, I tried to reduce the use of the counting variable `numDashes` and tried to the part where you check your range for all `-` to be more concise.  The below should work too, but might need a tweak or two:

```
Sub test2()
Dim cel As Range, rng As Range
Dim hideRow&

Set rng = Range("A1:A5")
hideRow = rng.Count + 1
'Check to see if your range is entirely made up of `-`
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "-") = rng.Count Then
    Rows(hideRow).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ' If you want to stop your macro if ALL range values are "-", then uncomment the next line:
    'Exit Sub
Else
    Rows(hideRow).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

For Each cel In rng
    If cel.Value = "-" Then
        Rows(cel.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, Wayne! The only tweak I made was an `Else` statement for the first `If` statement with the line `Rows(cel.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = False`. In my real excel doc, those values A1:A5 change based on the value in a cell in another sheet. Furthermore, this method is triggered only when a change in that cell occurs. This is probably why I had to add the `Else`. Thanks again!

Comment: @MarkRomano - So, this macro will run only when the value in A1:A5 changes?  You can make that a `Worksheet_Change` event to trigger automatically, and not have to guess/know if a cell has changed or not.

Comment: @MarkRomano - I just updated with an edit, perhaps it is a little quicker with the second method.

Comment: Thanks Bruce! I'll try it out later.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a formula in a helper column. I used this one for financial statements to suppress rows where multiple column are all zero to shorten up the report.

```
 =IF(AND(SUM(A7:R7)<1,SUM(A7:R7)>-1),IF(OR(ISNUMBER(LEFT(H7,4)),ISBLANK(H7),ISERR(VALUE(LEFT(H7,4)))),"Show","Hide"),"Show").
```

Then filter the rows by that column.

Comment: @BruceWayne thanks for editing the post. I'm new to this. How do you get the formula in a scroll? Looks like you didn't change it.

Comment: I just highlighted the formula, and clicked the code tags button (`{}`).